# socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known. When installing Cassandra on Docker on Windows 10 Professional

Tags: docker, cassandra, installation, windows-10

I try to install Cassandra on Docker on Windows 10 Professional. When I type:

> docker network create some-network

and after that:

> docker run -it --network some-network --rm cassandra cqlsh some-cassandra

then I get an error. I have entered it several times so I have downloaded the Cassandra image. Click on the link below (the error is highlighted in white):

[socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvpfp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Few things to note here:

Docker command to run any image goes like this:

```
docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

hence whatever you give at the end is taken as a list of arguments. Here in your case, `cqlsh` is the command and `some-cassandra` is an argument to `cqlsh` command

I dont think you are running a cassandra server, this command which you have specified **will only connect to a running instance of cassandra, this will not create a cassandra server**

You can run a server using this command:

```
docker run --name some-cassandra --network some-network -d cassandra
```

after running this, you can spin up another container for connecting to this server as a client using this command:

```
docker run -it --network some-network --rm cassandra cqlsh some-cassandra
```

Note that both of them are on the same network - `some-network` and in the second command we are passing reference to the first container as an argument to cqlsh command. The reference we are giving is the name of the container `some-cassandra`

Comment: Thanks for help. I also found solution on this page: https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/issues/207?fbclid=IwAR1Jp5Kxzp-sUZCsXsSWo38hDsC08rloO5-KMNLF-dt8HCf69tbZwVFt9sI

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I did not enter enough commands. I found solution there: 
https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra/issues/207?fbclid=IwAR1Jp5Kxzp-sUZCsXsSWo38hDsC08rloO5-KMNLF-dt8HCf69tbZwVFt9sI

Comment: It suppresses the error message, but nothing happened.